# Xamarin Forms iOS Navigation PushAsync shows Master Page Title on NavigationBar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

In my xamarin.forms project, Page1 is a detail page with master page title on navigatonbar. When i navigate to page3 from page1 viewmodel using PushAsync, page3 has got both master page title and navigationbar backbutton.When i navigate from page1 viewmodel  to page2 from inside master page,page2 has only navbackbutton,no master title.When navigating from page2 viewmodel to page3, page3 also do not have master title,only navbackbutton.I do not have this issue on Android.How to hide Master page Title when navigate from page1 viewmodel  to page3 on iOS?

page1 cs: vm method called for moving to page3

```
private async void Cart_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await img_cart.FadeTo(0.3, 500);
            await img_cart.FadeTo(1, 500);
            var vm = BindingContext as Main_page_vm;
            vm?.Save_cart();             
        }
```

Navigating from page1 viewmodel to page3: Detail page to content page having issue

```
internal async void Save_cart()
        {
            if(Number.Equals(0))
            {
                 App.Current.Properties["cartitems"] = purchaselist;
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().LongAlert("Empty cart !");
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Properties["cartitems"] = purchaselist;

                List<tb_login> Login_list = App.Database.Get_user_id();
                if (!Login_list.Count.Equals(0))
                {
                    foreach (tb_login tb_Login in Login_list)
                    {
                        App.Current.Properties["user_id"] = tb_Login.user_id;
                        App.Current.Properties["username"] = tb_Login.user_name;
                    }
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Address_page2()); //to page3,now showing master 
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                }
            }
        }
```

Page1 to page2: detail page to content page,No issues

```
        private async void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as HomePageMenuItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;
            if (item.Id == 0)
            {
               // Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomelyPage());
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomelyPage());//to page2 has no master issues
            }
            IsPresented = false;

            MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

Page2 viewmodel to page3:content page to content page,No issues

```
public async void Save_cart()
        {
            if (Number.Equals(0))
            {
                 App.Current.Properties["cartitems"] = purchaselist;
                DependencyService.Get<IToast>().LongAlert("Empty cart !");
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.Properties["cartitems"] = purchaselist;

                List<tb_login> Login_list = App.Database.Get_user_id();
                if (!Login_list.Count.Equals(0))
                {
                    foreach (tb_login tb_Login in Login_list)
                    {
                        App.Current.Properties["user_id"] = tb_Login.user_id;
                        App.Current.Properties["username"] = tb_Login.user_name;
                    }
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Address_page2()); //to page3,also not showing master
                }
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                }
            }
        }
```

page1 xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OnRestaur.Views.Main_Page"
             BackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="Small" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,32,10"  Style="{StaticResource Label_font}" TextColor="White">
                </Label>
                <Image Source="shoppingcart_white.png" x:Name="img_cart" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="60" HeightRequest="50" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Cart_Tapped" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>        
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Page3 xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OnRestaur.Views.Address_page2"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             Title=" ">   
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Spacing="0" Padding="0">            
            <Image Source="back_arrow.png" x:Name="img_cart" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Back_arrow_Tapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>         
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

page2 xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Home"
             x:Class="OnRestaur.Views.HomelyPage"
             xmlns:local="OnRestaur.Views;assembly=ContentView"
             xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False">
    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="back_arrow.png"   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="30" HeightRequest="30" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Back_arrow_Tapped" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">                
                <Image Source="loc.png" x:Name="img_cart" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" Margin="0,0,30,0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Loc_Tapped" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you changing the titles? I was not able to find it in this code!

Comment: Master page comes when navigate from detail page(page1) to content page(page3).From content page(page2) to content(page3),no issues.updated question

Comment: I guess I did not ask my question properly, you are saying that your title is not changing properly its okay but where are you changing the title in code?

Comment: Did you try setting Title ="" in page 3 ?

Comment: Maybe there is some logic problem when navigating from page1 viewmodel to page3.You can expose more code where Set Title.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT added xaml.need `NavigationPage.TitleView` in page3.removing titleview removes master.but need titleview also

Comment: @pooja added xaml in question. not helping;titleview also there.removing titleview solves issue,but need titleview.

Comment: @G.hakim added xaml in question. Removing titleview in page3 solves issue(master removed),but need titleview there

Comment: @G.hakim Navigated from page1 vm to page3 like this `await Navigation.PushAsync(new Address_page2());` before;now changed to `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Address_page2());` solved issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Navigation to something like below and it should solve your issue:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Address_page2());
```